# Missing orcalculum+ for Ultima Weapon

Tags: kingdom-hearts-3

I’m literally missing a orcalculum+! I just started gathering them, and gathered the one from Pirates in the chest and the one from final world in the chest. It said I obtained one both times but my invetory only says I have only one! Went back to the chests and they are both opened.

Like what? Am I not going to be able to get the Ultima weapon now?

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question about where your ore went. This will guide you on how to actually get the ore (which answers your `not able to get` question). Check this article out: https://www.gamespot.com/articles/kingdom-hearts-3-ultima-weapon-guide-orichalcum-lo/1100-6464756/

Answer (score 2):

If you opened both chests, but only have one in your inventory, then it sounds like you visited the Moogle Workshop prior to obtaining the other Orichalcum+.

Each time you visit the Moogle Workshop, all currently possessed materials (including Orichalcum+) will be moved out of your inventory and into the Moogle Workshop.

To verify this, open the Moogle Workshop menu and view "Materials List". This will provide a list of how many materials you possess for synthesization.

Comment: yes - when working on Synthesis stuff, always use the Materials list in the workshop and never your inventory.